# Get list of subscribers (for in-app purchase) from Apple?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My team has launched an app with in-app purchases. We are storing the receipt generated by Apple on our own servers and associating them with corresponding user id's.

A couple of users are claiming that they made in-app purchases, but we don't see records of their receipts on our database server. I'm worried that they might have gotten lost due to network issues.

Is it possible (as a developer) to ask Apple for a list of users who've bought in-app purchases for my app? Or confirm if someone bought something without them needing to make a new subscription?

I have this nagging feeling that I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Can the user send you an email confirmation of the purchase from Apple? You might call Apple about this?

Comment: One of the users sent in a screenshot of the purchase from her iPhone, but I'm a bit skeptical if its legit. The email confirmation, yes that's something worth checking. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find it ? How to get list of subscribers ?